# Declare varchar in python

Tags: python, sql, variables, declare

How can i declare a variable in sql in python ?

I have tried this so fare:

```
import re
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('imdb1.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE imdb1 (ROWID int, Title varchar(40), Rating int)''')

x = open("ratings.list.txt","r")
movread = x.readlines()
x.close()



#s = raw_input('Search: ').lower()
for ns in movread:


    if 'the lord of the' in ns.lower():
        d = re.split('\s+',ns,4)
        Title = d[4].rstrip()
        Rating= d[3]

        list = [Title,Rating]

        print list
        # Insert a row of data
        c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb1 ( Title, Rating) values ("%s","%s")'%(list[0],list[1]))
        conn.commit()
```

Output:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-0d9cfec4960a> in <module>()
     25         print list
     26         # Insert a row of data
---> 27         c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb1 ( Title, Rating) values ("%s","%s")'%(list[0],list[1]))
     28         conn.commit()
     29 

OperationalError: near "5": syntax error
['The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King (2003)', '8.9']
['The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)', '8.8']
['The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)', '8.7']
['"5 Second Movies" (2007) {The Lord of the Rings and the Two Towers (#1.63)}', '6.2']
```

So it looks like when i reach "5 in the bottom, i cant put the list into my sqldb
How can i do that ? 
I have tried to declare variable type but it did not work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that the string your substituting in has quotes.  Rather than using python's string formatting, you should probably use sqlite's:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO imdb1 ( Title, Rating) values (?, ?)', (list[0],list[1]))
```

Note that this is a general principle that you should abide by when formatting strings for a database.  With a maliciously formatted movie title, a user could potentially corrupt your database<sup>1</sup> (known as [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

<sup><sup>1</sup>I'm not really sure how much damage they could do here as sqlite's execute only executes a single statement, but I'm sure that others with more experience than I could probably concoct some pretty nasty things regardless.</sup>

Comment: I don't think you want the quotes round the ? chars.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- Probably not.  I've never used sqlite, but I recently decided that I should try to learn some stuff about databases, etc.  Answering questions around here is my fast track to learning how to _actually_ do it right ;-)

Comment: It worked :D  can somone help me with generating the ROWID it says none right now ?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Updated with a mention of sql injection.

Comment: @user3322871: Declare `rowid` with type `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` instead of `INT` and it will autoincrement. A skim of the [docs](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) suggests you don't even need to declare `rowid` as one is maintained implicitly.  (It would have been good to have asked your followup as a seperate question.  It gives future visitors to stackoverflow a better opportunity to find the question if they have a similar problem.  As a bonus, you would also get meaningless internet points for your seperate question.)